# How to get coordinates of a selected point in R plot?

Tags: r

I need to pass to R program coordinates of a point selected by the mouse pointer, to perform some calculations. I have problems getting it to work.

I know that this code should identify point on a plot:

```
plot(kk2$k2,kk2$k1)
identify(kk2$k2,kk2$k1)
```

But even that doesn't work. On a plot appears some meaningless number, while point has two coordinates. why?

How to fix at least that?

My goal is to have the point coordinates returned to R and perform some calculations on them. The dataset kk2 has only two columns - k1 and k2, nothing more.

Comment: You might find the function in [this excellent blog post](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2014/12/point-locator-function.html) to be useful.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, can you please assist me in locating the lowest coordinate points in the graph, for example, in multiple lines graph, if the lowest point is (17, 2.3333), how to locate this point only in r graph? I would appreciate for your assistance.

Answer (score 5):

The package "gatepoints" available on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gatepoints) will allow you to draw a gate returning your points of interest.

If you are using RStudio it is better to plot in a separate x11 window by first opening a new x11 device:

```
X11()
```

Now plot your points, I've made up some simple data:

```
kk2 <- data.frame(k2=1:10, k1=1:10)
plot(kk2, col = "red", pch = 16)
```

[image: Simple plot]

Run the command below and then select your points by left clicking and right clicking to close the polygon:

```
selectedPoints <- fhs(kk2)
```

[image]

This will return:

```
selectedPoints
#> [1] "4" "5" "7"
#> attr(,"gate")
#>         k2       k1
#> 1 6.099191 8.274120
#> 2 8.129107 7.048649
#> 3 8.526881 5.859404
#> 4 5.700760 6.716428
#> 5 5.605314 5.953430
#> 6 6.866882 3.764390
#> 7 3.313575 3.344069
#> 8 2.417270 5.217868
```

Answer (score 3):

```
locator {graphics}  R Documentation
Graphical Input

Description

Reads the position of the graphics cursor when the (first) mouse button is pressed.

![> pts <- locator(4)
> polygon(pts)
> png(); plot(1,1)
> pts <- locator(4)
> polygon(pts)
> dev.off()][1]
```

Comment: but that doesn't seem identify the point present on a plot, just coordinate on a cursor. if I am not precise enough I may think I click a point, but I get a point that I very close to that point but not identical.

Comment: Questions without reproducible examples are intrinsically unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, since `identify` returns the `seq_along(x)` for the point that you click near (what you refer to as 'some meaningless number'):

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x,y)
out <- sapply(list(x,y),"[",identify(x,y))
# do some clicking
out
# something like this is returned for the x/y points
#            [,1]        [,2]
#[1,] -0.62221766 -0.73838314
#[2,] -0.69896643  0.40186536
#[3,]  0.06077831 -1.63940474
#[4,] -0.09900270  0.00062011
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is using the result as an index. This can then be used to identify the specific xy coordinates:

```
n <- 10
x <- runif(n)
y <- runif(n)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)

plot(y ~ x, data=df)
df[identify(x, y, n=1),]
```